# i can't open IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1（FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed）

Tags: intellij-idea

I have installed idea, and I cannot open idea by double-clicking the .exe file, so there is no response at all. If I choose to open idea.bat with the command line, such an error will be reported ,

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)     at 
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
            at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:513)
            at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at fuck_the_regulations_v300.bj.b(bj.java)
            at fuck_the_regulations_v300.p.premain(p.java)
            ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            ... 8 more
    *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at ./src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 422
    FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed
```

Comment: My problem is solved, the specific solution is to delete the idea64.exe.vmoptions file
-javaagent: the first line of code, I don’t know why but it is solved, share it

Comment: I'm having this same problem on macOS but cannot tell what has changed to cause it all of a sudden.

Comment: Upgrading to 2021.3.2 resolved the issue for now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to locate the file `idea64.exe.vmoptions`

[I have mine here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIZia.png)

then modify the file and delete the `label-javaagent` or Related labels

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I knew that Intelli 2021.3.2 should work in my PC as I was able to install it in Windows Sandbox just fine.

So what I did next, knowing that it works on a clean windows system was to go to Run Command and type

```
%APPDATA%
```

Once inside the explorer window, delete the Directory JetBrains since this contains the old installation configurations of your old IntelliJ installations and may be causing the issue.

After deleting this, I was finally able to run IntelliJ alright. :)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same trouble. Did you delete just the first line (in my case it is: "-Xms128m") or the whole file?

Comment: No, I mean in the idea64.exe.vmoptions file, there is a line of code starting with -javaagent:, like this -javaagent:D\idea\intellijIDEA 2020.1.1\bin\jetbrains-agent.jar, I only Deleted this line of code.